# Complex Variables & Residues

Tags: complex-analysis

My LaTex skills are woefully inadequate. But I don't need them this minute.
Suppose upon integration of a complex valued function, along a "nice closed" path surrounding singularities, you recognize that two of the pieces, (usually semi-circles or triangles or line segments, for example), are homotopic, then may I say that they make the same (up to +/- sign) contribution to the residue around the complete path?
For example, an inverted equilateral triangle (built on the axes) has two sides with non-zero slope which are, of course, homotopic. Will they do as I've asked?

Comment: For example, if f(z) = z^2/(4x^2+1) then there are poles of order one at +/- i at +/-/2i and the "closed path" of integration is the equilateral triangle given by y=1, and the sides y = x and y=-x everything is a function of t, for t  in  [-1, 1.], with line segments parameterized via R(t) = a(1-t) + tb where a & b are the endpoints (as vectors),  of the, "corners" of the triangle. I hope this is suffucuent. If not, please fix.

Answer (score 0):

You did not state  in your example of there is a singularity inside the equilateral triangle, and that missing information is needed in order to answer your question thoroughly.

The general principle is this. Both closed loop path integrals will agree  if the deformation does not cross any singularities; but if any singularities are crossed in the deformation process then the integral along the new closed path might change.

Stated with somewhat more rigor, the path integrals are unaltered by the homotopy if the homotopy takes place  in the open region $\Omega$ where the function $f(z)$ is analytic (*hence free of singularities*).